# Bitbucket: Put the latest commit hash to a file in the repository

Tags: bitbucket, cicd, bitbucket-pipelines

I would like to have a way to have a file changed in the repo to the latest git commit hash, or a random string. (which we could use to append after our .css / .js files as the file version)

I have found several topics online on how to put the latest hash in a variable, but I'm not able to find the correct method to edit a file in the current repository. Am I thinking the wrong way or am i missing something?

As a small note: Is there a more effecient way to have a file hash after .css?v={VERSION} without calculating the hash on every request?

Update: I found that i could create a file with "echo $CI_COMMIT_SHA > version.txt"

I also have the following step now:

```
versioning_job:
  stage: versioning
  script:
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_SHA > version.txt
    - git add version.txt
    - git commit -m "Add version.txt with commit SHA"
    - git push
```

But now I am getting the error

- git push
  remote: Permission denied to update branch master.
  To http://bitbucket.org/XXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX
- [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
  error: failed to push some refs to 'http://bitbucket.org/XXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXX'

I assume this is because the CLI does not have the required permissions to push to this remote because it is a private repo.

Comment: So, what is the actual question? Best practices for versioning static files and invalidating past distributions? How to push back to bitbucket.org from a pipeline step?

Comment: @N1ngu Pretty much what the title of the question states. How to put the latest commit hash in a file in the repository in a pipeline step.

Comment: Well, you already figured the `echo $CI_COMMIT_SHA > version.txt` (I think it should be `$BITBUCKET_COMMIT`, I fear you might be pasting code from Gitlab pipelines). You can go ahead and answer your own question but I feel like there's something more you want to ask.

Comment: Not the answer, but I think you should fill version.txt on deploy with a timestamp and not with a commit hash in the repo.

Comment: I think you should include such things in the package you deploy, instead of almost doubling your commit history...

Comment: @Randommm Including this in the package requires us to have about 250 devices set-up so that it all includues this. With this configuration we don't need any setup for all the devices. Commit history doesn't really matter for us.